# Create custom url shortcuts in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, url-shortening

I want to create *custom* URL shortcuts in Chrome, such that hitting '**foo**' in the omni/address bar will be the equivalent of hitting 'http://bar.com'.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can create bookmark entries and for the title specify your "short" name, thus when you enter that short name in the address bar it will be displayed in suggestion box. Not exactly sure if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by adding a "search engine" even though it isn't strictly a search engine.

Enter `chrome://settings/searchEngines` to view the current settings. If you scroll down to the bottom of the pane there are 3 inputs for adding a search engine name, keyword and URL. If you add `foo`, `foo`, `http://bar.com/` and select <kbd>Done</kbd> then entering foo in the omnibar will take you to `http://bar.com`.

Comment: Not perfect, but the best solution I've found to my needs so far. Thx.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's not perfect but at least this way the shortcuts sync if you sign in to Chrome and sync `Settings`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply edit your [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and add a host definition like so:

```
1.2.3.4    foo
```

Where `1.2.3.4` is the IP of `bar.com` and `foo` is the shortcut you want to call it.Save the file, open any browser and type `foo` in the address bar, that should take you to `http://1.2.3.4`.

This should work for all OSs, at least for Linux, Windows and OSX (or any Unix). The only thing that changes is the location of the `hosts` file:

- Linux/Unix/OSX : `/etc/hosts`
- Windows >=7 : `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

For other OSs, see the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system).

Answer (score 0):

The [Quickmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickmarks/piefpokhpcehbeelhohgcnbipnfkogig) extension does something very close to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I created a chrome extension for doing exactly this.

It allows you to define a URL shortcut and when you search for that shortcut it will navigate to the website you have saved.

Download the extension here.

[Web Aliases](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-aliases/hdempabimjppagbgpiglikbobneoegmp)

Here is a nick name I created using the example you gave.

"foo" -> "https://www.bar.com/"

[image: web alias example]